# How to access class constants and variables

Tags: ios, swift

Why can I not perform operations with a variable or constant at the class level?  Is this not allowed or is there a keyword I need to use to access them?  Is this bad practice?

Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let one = 1
    let two = 2
    var sum = one + two
}
```

Error:

`ViewController.Type does not have a member named 'one'`

Comment: put sum = one + two, in viewDidLoad or similar

Comment: You can declare variables at the class level, and assign initial values to them but you can't have arbitrary code outside of a function

Comment: @Paulw11 What is the preferred method of storing data from a function so that its available to every method in the class?

Comment: You could make a computed class level property or simply a class function that returns the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class variables and constants must be `static`, e.g., `static let one = 1`.

Here it suffices for the two `let` constants to be `static` for them to be usable in initializing both class and instance variables. The following works for me:

```
class MyClass {
    static let one = 1
    static let two = 2
    static var sum = one + two
    var instanceProduct = one * two
}

MyClass.one
MyClass.sum
MyClass().instanceProduct
```

Note that in the above example you can do `MyClass.sum = 5`. If you meant the sum to be constant as well, simply change it to `static let sum = one + two`.

The requirement is that the constants you use outside of any functions and closures be declared `static let`. The implication of this is that they are truly constant for the entire class. If you need instance-specific constants, you cannot use them outside of functions or closures (as you've noticed) – as a workaround for a variable `sum` I would suggest a `lazy` variable initialized by a closure:

```
class MyClass {
    let one: Int // value given in `init`
    let two = 2
    lazy var sum: Int = { self.one + self.two }()

    init(one: Int = 1) {
        self.one = one
    }
}
MyClass().sum // 3
MyClass(one: 2).sum // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var result = one + two
    }
```

Comment: Does not happen on the class level so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DogCoffee Will `result` be accessible to the class's methods?  Can I call `result` in `func xyz()`?

Comment: If you are performing a calculation on 2 variables I'd use a method that returns the result, be it a class or instance method.